# getting contact phone number

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
while (people.moveToNext()){
    int NameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int NumIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);

    String Name = people.getString(NameIndex);
    //String Num = people.getString(NumIndex);

    myArr.add(Name.toString());
    myNum.add(Num.toString());

}
```

Hello I am experiencing problems retrieving a contact's phone number where each time i enable this line of code

```
String Num = people.getString(NumIndex);
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.GhattasAk.RingMe/com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at com.GhattasAk.RingMe.Main.onCreate(Main.java:49)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-03 15:38:30.436: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  ... 11 more
```

the application crashes.. I do not understand why

this is the edit to get a name based on a number is this true ?

```
              if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
              {
                //  Find contact based on name.
                  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                  Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                      "NUMBER = '" + number + "'", null, null);
                  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                      String contactId =
                          cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                      //  Get all phone numbers.
                      Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                          Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                      while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                          String numb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                      }
                      phones.close();
                   }
                  cursor.close();
```

Comment: Post your logcat error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably becouse the contact have multiple phone nrs like work...
try this:

```
//  Find contact based on name.
        //
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String contactId =
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            //
            //  Get all phone numbers.
            //
            Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                switch (type) {
                    case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        // do something with the Home number here...
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        // do something with the Mobile number here...
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        // do something with the Work number here...
                        break;
                    }
            }
            phones.close();
         }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: the contacts are on the emulator and i added only 1 number each

Comment: get field slot from row 0 col -1 is shown when android can't find the information into the cell from db so please get my methode and try to see if it's working fine

Comment: ok just a second so i update this to retrieve a name based on a calling number

Comment: i added an edit but i am unsure if it is correct it is for retrieving the contact name based on the calling number

Comment: So what is wrong, it's working? have you check the phone nr? is correct?

Comment: i am confused on the idea of having a name with multiple numbers if a contact is calling i will get his number but does the function search all the number field in the directory for a name ? or is this an issue i have to deal with as well

Comment: The idea is that a contact can have multiple phone numbers so you have to stablish a priority for those and ofcource if the contact have only one number save him. Yes the function search in all the number fields area for that contact name. It is not hard to manage multyple phone numbers for a contact just make a string variable and for any times of phone nr just check if exist if yes initialize the string in order that you want...I think by default is the mobile value